# Any technology for full body video with slides in Zoom

Tags: lecture-tools, information-technology

Given the surge of COVID cases many of us have to find different ways for giving online lectures. I use Zoom for lectures and I would like to know if there is any technology or combination of technologies in order to get a presentation in which slides are from my computer and the view of the instructor comes from the camera in a full body view. I would like something like in the image:
[image]

Any ideas or suggestions about software I can use to get a similar effect?

Comment: The full body bit is all about the lens, and distance from the camera.

Comment: I can not see how this is about teaching computing.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly easily achievable with [OBS](https://obsproject.com/). There are [some plugins](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/) that can help you with setting it up with Zoom. You need to:

1. Set up a fairly big [Green Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) with decent lighting.
2. Capture the video feed of the person presenting via any camera. OBS makes it trivial to remove the uniform background and make it transparent (the Green Screen). Keep in mind that the correct and uniform illumination is important - otherwise some artifacts could appear in the image.
3. OBS makes it (once again) trivial to lay the camera feed with background made transparent on some presentation.

The only downside is that the instructor speaks to the camera and points (if they point to anything at all) to a big, green wall of fabric. It's an inconvenience to them, but the end-user effect is quite spectacular (just like in the screenshot you've provided).